# How do you "from __future__ import division" in boost::python?

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I am using boost::python with Python 2.7. I would like to enable Python 3.0-style division for a call to boost::python::eval, as you would from a Python program using

```
from __future__ import division
```

This looks like it should work, although it will pull in all of **future**, not just the division method:

```
boost::python::object mainModule = boost::python::import( "__main__" );
boost::python::object mainNamespace = mainModule.attr( "__dict__" );
mainNamespace[ "__future__" ] = boost::python::import( "__future__" );

return boost::python::eval(
  myExpression,
  mainNamespace,
  mainNamespace );
```

Unfortunately, the expression is still evaluated using Python 2.x style division.

1. What is the proper way to enable **future** in boost::Python?
2. How do you import a single method, rather than an entire library, using boost::python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It seems like the best way would be to initialize the interpreter with a script that imports the features from **future** that you want.
2. You can import a subset of the module using exec and the import statement. Because of how future works, supplying directives to code compiled by an exec statement, you cannot simply import in an exec and then perform an evaluation.

The documentation states that:

> A future statement typed at an interactive interpreter prompt will take effect for the rest of the interpreter session. If an interpreter is started with the -i option, is passed a script name to execute, and the script includes a future statement, it will be in effect in the interactive session started after the script is executed.

It may be possible initialize the interpreter in the Python C API to use future by executing a script that has the desired future import. I wasn't able to get this to work. But I could be utilizing the API wrong.

An alternative, would be something like the following:

```
boost::python::object main_module = boost::python::import("__main__");
boost::python::object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");
std::string evalString = "3/2";
std::stringstream evalStringFunction;
evalStringFunction << "from __future__ import division\n";
evalStringFunction << "def evalWithFuture(): return " << evalString;
boost::python::exec(evalStringFunction.str().c_str(), main_namespace,
                  main_namespace);
boost::python::object result =  boost::python::eval("evalWithFuture()", main_namespace, main_namespace);
```

The idea here is that the function evalWithFuture will be compiled with the future import. Because it's an expression, you can use it in your evaluation call and it will use the proper future division operator.

Comment: Too bad eval won't work. Maybe someday. I was trying to avoid exec, but like you, I don't see a better alternative.